# How to optimize looping through Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I know that looping through a Pandas dataframe is usually a bad idea, but in this case I am not sure what to do else. I have the DataFrame called **merged** of the following format, but 2kk rows long. 
merged['time'] = merged['year'] * 4 + merged['qtr']

```
year    qtr   time  election_year   PostElection
1976    1     7905      NaN                0
1976    2     7906      NaN                0
1976    3     7907      NaN                0
1976    4     7908      NaN                0
1977    1     7909      NaN                0
1977    2     7910      NaN                0
1977    3     7911      NaN                0
1977    4     7912      NaN                0
```

What I am trying to do is to label each row if it was the election year, based on the calculations below, and keep the rest of the observations as NaNs and also change PostElection column from 0 to 1, if the following condition yields to true. Here's the first iteration of my code, using a for loop:

```
elect_yrs = list(range(1976,2017,4))
for i, year in enumerate(merged.year):

    if year in elect_yrs and merged.loc[i, 'time'] > (year*4-3) and merged.loc[i, 'time'] <= (year*4+10) and merged.loc[i, 'time'] != (year*4+4):
        merged.loc[i, 'election_year'] = year

    if merged.loc[i, 'time'] > (year*4+4) and merged.loc[i, 'time'] <= (year*4+10):
        merged.loc[i, 'PostElection'] = 1
```

It is extremely slow. I waited for half an hour and gave up. Did a counter just to see how fast the numbers are growing, not fast, but working. 
My second iteration is using the zip function. I've read somewhere that it's four times faster than a for loop. According to the speed of counter, it's is faster, but still taking a lot of time. Right now it's been 20 minutes and still running.

```
elect_yrs = list(range(1976,2017,4))
for year,time,i in zip(merged['year'], merged['time'], range(len(merged))):
    if year in elect_yrs and time > (year*4-3) and time <= (year*4+10) and time != (year*4+4):
        merged.loc[i, 'election_year'] = year
    if time > (year*4+4) and time <= (year*4+10):
        merged.loc[i, 'PostElection'] = 1
```

Any ideas on how to improve this thing? Wish I paid more attention in my Computer Science class.....

Answer (score 0):

Decided to give up on the loop. Created a miniature dataframe with desired variables, performed the for loop on it, got the result I needed and merged it back to the original dataframe using a left join. 1000 times faster.